# MySQL attendance table

Tags: mysql

currently I am working on the database related to the student attendance tracking. The three main tables that I am dealing with is students,modules and attendance. The

structure of students is
(studentID,name , surname , email , attendance)

structure of modules is
(moduleID, module,startTime,EndTime)

and structure of attendance is
(studentID , scanTime).

And basically what I need to do here is to increase attendance in (students) table by +1 if the scanTime in (attendance) is between the startTime and EndTime in (module).Im not sure do I need to use any joins here or is it going to be just IF statements. I would appreciate if you can share sql commands. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is `modules` connected to attendance? When you've answered this, you should have a look at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html and have a try. Post where you get stuck. This is a site where we **help**, not where we do the whole job.

Answer (score -1):

Create a stored procedure that would check and update it for you.

Comment: can you explain that in bit more details , please